# Is it safe to sign the metrics-server certificate and key with the Cluster CA?

Tags: kubernetes, pki

I'm trying to install metrics-server and I'm not sure what to do with the `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file`.

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server

Can I use a certificate and key that is signed by the Cluster CA?  Or is this bad unsafe for production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says in the referenced docs,

`--tls-cert-file, --tls-private-key-file: the serving certificate and key files. If not specified, self-signed certificates will be generated, but it's recommended that you use non-self-signed certificates in production.`

As a general rule, providing certs of your own CA would be the safest option.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So why would using my own CA be safer than using the cluster's CA?  And if I use my own CA, where should I store it?  Not sure if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: What I mean is the cluster CA signed tls-certificates are better than the self- signed ones, that’s all.

Comment: I re-read that quote and I don't know why I thought it was telling me to use my own CA to sign metric-server's certificates.  Thanks for the help!